# Webmatrix & Umbraco: restoring a database from a .bak file

Tags: sql-server, umbraco, webmatrix

I have a project written in the cms Umbraco.  I was given the source code from another developer along with a `.bak` file of the database. What I am wondering is how I can import the database into the project?

To fix this problem I opened the project in Webmatrix (the ide). Then I went to the database tab and found there was a database with a network path not found. I looked around the settings, but I could not find a restore from `.bak` option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be running SQL Server. You should be able to use SQL Server Express (free version).  Umbraco requires SQL Server 2008 or newer but if the .BAK is from a newer version, you will want that version or newer.  You will also need SQL Server Management Studio.  With that, you can restore from the back up by connecting to your database server (possibly running  locally), right clicking the "Databases" node and select "Restore Database..."  Select "Device" under Source and select your .BAK file.  [This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/50354/restoring-a-sql-database-backup-using-sql-server-management-studio/) covers the steps in more detail.

Once the database is restored, you may want to create a new user with a sql login. Then you need to update the database connection string in your web.config so it can connect.